# Error while saving flow

Tags: visual-workflow, flow

I am using flows, in this case there is a flow that cancels a Case. It was functioning ok, until I added a new field in Case Object (Note di annullamento) and wanted to map it with the input field Note in the Flow. When trying to Save the flow As a new version, a strange error appears. Any idea?

P.S. There is screenshot of the error attached[image: error]

Comment: Showing the new field that you added to case object would be useful as well

Comment: It is a text field "Note", 255 chars. Mapping with flow fields is working only with existent fields on sfdc, not with the new ones

Comment: @BarCotter any idea on this issue?

Comment: It sounds like theres something wrong with the new field you added so double check that.

Comment: Thanks for answering. In fact the problem happens with every new field :( I think there might be a bug in SFDC otherwise I can't explain this strange issue..

Comment: You may have to raise a case with salesforce